# Disable ScriptManager script consolidation in development?

Tags: asp.net, scriptmanager

In an ASP.NET site, I have a ScriptManager control on a Master page and ScriptManagerProxy controls all over the place. In most cases I use the `<compositescript>` block to combine scripts into a single file.

**Core.Master**

```
<asp:scriptmanager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server"  >
    <compositescript>
        <scripts>
            <asp:scriptreference path="script1.js" />
            <asp:scriptreference path="script2.js" />
            ... etc ...
        </scripts>
    </compositescript>
</asp:scriptmanager>
```

**Sample control or content page**

```
<asp:scriptmanagerproxy runat="server">
    <compositescript>
        <scripts>
            <asp:scriptreference path="script3.js" />
            <asp:scriptreference path="script4.js" />
            ... etc ... 
        </scripts>
    </compositescript>
</asp:scriptmanagerproxy>
```

This works fine, but in order to effectively use Visual Studio's client-side debugging tools, I'd prefer not to consolidate the scripts while developing.

I've tried just moving all the scripts from `<compositescripts>` to `<scripts>`, thusly:

```
    Private Sub ScriptManager1_PreRender(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ScriptManager1.PreRender
        ' In development, don't combine scripts
        If IsDevelopmentEnvironment() Then
            For Each s As ScriptReference In ScriptManager1.CompositeScript.Scripts.Reverse
                ScriptManager1.Scripts.Insert(0, s)
            Next
            ScriptManager1.CompositeScript.Scripts.Clear()
        End If
    End Sub
```

This works like a charm, for the scripts in the ScriptManager itself. It doesn't see the scripts in the various ScriptManagerProxy controls, though, and those still get consolidated. While debugging I can see a ScriptManager1.Proxies collection that I'd love to iterate through, but it's "Friend" so I can't actually access it in code.

Disabling consolidation in development seems like a fairly obvious requirement, so maybe there's a much more obvious way to do this that I'm just missing?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Does [ScriptMode="Debug"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.scriptmode.aspx) vs. Release work?

Comment: No, it still consolidates regardless of how ScriptMode is set.